# What is the derivative of $y=\sqrt{\frac {1- \sin(x)}{1+\sin(x)}}$

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

The solution to the question is given in the book I'm currently studying, but I can't understand it. I used Wolfram Alpha and I got a completely different answer. Here's the Solution from the book:
[image]

[image]

I don't understand how
$$\frac{-2\cos x}{(1+\sin x)^2}$$
got inside the under root? (From the third line to fourth.) when it's actually not apart.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand it either.

Comment: Probably a formatting error with braces

Comment: Do you think it is even right? Coz i get different answer from Wolfram, and when I try rationalising method

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is a mistake in your book at this example.

$$\frac{-2\cos x}{(1+\sin x)^2}$$
This shouldn't be inside the root.

All you need to do is:

Apply the chain rule over $$\sqrt{\frac {1- \sin(x)}{1+\sin(x)}}$$

And for differentiating $\frac {1- \sin(x)}{1+\sin(x)}$, you'll need to apply the quotient rule.

As a result, you'll get
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac {1- \sin(x)}{1+\sin(x)}}} \cdot (- \frac{2cos(x)}{(1+sin(x))^2})$$

After that, you do a simplification to find the following result:
$$- \frac{cos(x)}{\sqrt{-sin(x) + 1} \cdot (sin(x) + 1)^\frac{3}{2}}$$

I hope I made it clear for you.

Comment: You can simplify this expression by using $\cos(x)^2 + \sin(x)^2 = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, by $\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) = \frac{\sin(\theta)}{1 + \cos(\theta)}$ we can use that

$$\frac {1- \sin(x)}{1+\sin(x)} =\tan^2\left(\frac \pi 4-\frac x 2 \right)\ge 0$$

and then

$$y=\sqrt{\frac {1- \sin(x)}{1+\sin(x)}} =\tan\left(\frac \pi 4-\frac x 2 \right)$$

therefore by $\cos^2(x) = {1 + \cos(2x) \over 2}$ we obtain

$$y'=-\frac1{2\cos^2\left(\frac \pi 4-\frac x 2 \right)}=-\frac1{1+\sin x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different way to approach the problem.

Write $y^2 = \frac{1- \sin(x)}{1 + \sin(x)}$ (simply squared both sides)

Now differentiate both sides w.r.t $x$:

$2y {dy \over dx} = \frac{-2 \cos(x)}{(1+ \sin(x))^2}$. The right side is based on ${d \over dx}{f \over g} = \frac{gf' - fg'}{g^2}$ and the left side is based on chain rule.

Now you have (simple substitution):

${dy \over dx} = -{1 \over y}\frac{\cos(x)}{(1+ \sin(x))^2} = -\sqrt{{1+\sin(x) \over 1 - \sin(x)}}\frac{\cos(x)}{(1+ \sin(x))^2}$

Recall $\cos(x) = 1-\sin^2(x)$, i.e. $\cos(x) = \sqrt{(1-\sin(x))(1+\sin(x))}$. Substitute to get:

${dy \over dx} = -\sqrt{{1+\sin(x) \over 1 - \sin(x)}} {\sqrt{(1-\sin(x))(1+\sin(x))} \over (1+ \sin(x))^2}$

Simple algebra now to conclude:

${dy \over dx} = {-1 \over 1+\sin(x)}$.

Many ways to skin the cat.